# filemtime(): stat failed warning within a child theme

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I am trying to work on my child theme, but I can't get rid of the `filemtime(): stat failed` warning, which appeared as soon as I activated my child theme.
After reading other questions, I understand that the filemtime warning is often caused by incorrect use of URLs and paths. However, I think I provided URLs and paths correctly, and if that's the case, then there is something else I'm missing.

This function is from the parent theme:

```
function mtt_styles()
{
    wp_enqueue_style(
    'mtt-custom-style', 
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/css/custom-style.css', 
    false, 
    filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/dist/css/custom-style.css'), 
    'all'
    );
  
    wp_enqueue_style('mtt-main-style', get_stylesheet_uri());    
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mtt_styles');
```

This is from my child theme:

```
function child_styles()
{
    $theme = wp_get_theme();    
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'mtt-custom-style',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/css/custom-style.css',
        array(),
        filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/dist/css/custom-style.css'),
        'all'
    );
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'mtt-main-style',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array(),
        $theme->parent()->get('Version'),
        'all'
    );
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'child-main-style', 
        get_stylesheet_uri(), 
        array('mtt-custom-style', 'mtt-main-style'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_styles');
```

When I go to the page source, I see that the enqueueing worked. All the files are there, and all the styles from the parent theme work well within the child, but the warning remains.

Could someone help me spot what I am missing or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your parent theme. The parent theme is using `get_stylesheet_directory()` here:

```
filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/dist/css/custom-style.css'),
```

When the parent theme is active, that's fine, because `get_stylesheet_directory()` will point that file in the parent theme. The problem is that when you activate a child theme, it is trying to get the `filemtime()` of `'/dist/css/custom-style.css'` in your *child theme*, and I'm guessing that this file doesn't exist there. Hence the failure.

The issue is that because `filemtime()` is run right away, it doesn't matter if you re-define the script's URL, or dequeue it, because it's already tried and failed to check the time, throwing the error.

If you're the author of the parent theme, then fixing the issue is as simple has replacing `get_stylesheet_directory()` with `get_template_directory_uri()` (or better yet, [`get_parent_theme_file_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_parent_theme_file_path/)). Then the error won't occur when loading a stylesheet that's missing that file, and you won't need to re-eneueue it from that child theme.

If you're not the original author, then the right solution would be to just unhook `mtt_styles()` from `wp_enqueue_scripts` entirely. Then from the child theme just re-enqueue them using the correct path. You're already doing the latter, so you just need to do the unhooking part. The trick with that is that you'll need to unhook it from within the `after_setup_theme` hook, because otherwise the original hook will not have been added yet otherwise, since the child theme is loaded first:

```
add_action(
    'after_setup_theme',
    function()
    {
        remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mtt_styles' );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 major problems here:

### Problem 1: `get_template__....` and  `get_stylehsheet_...` are not the same

`filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/dist/css/custom-style.css'),` means get the file modified time of the parent themes `dist/css/custom-style.css` file.

I suspect, there is no such file in the parent theme because it exists only in the child theme, so PHP fires off a warning that you asked for the file modified time of a file that does not exist.

`get_template_directory` and `get_stylesheet_directory` do not do the same thing.

- `get_template_directory` is the parent theme ( current if not using a child theme
- `get_stylesheet_directory` is the current theme, aka the child theme

The same goes for all the other functions starting with `get_template_...` and `get_stylesheet_...`

### Problem 2: A Misunderstanding of `functions.php` in child and parent themes, and how child themes work.

If you use a child theme, the parent themes `functions.php` still runs. Child themes don't let you override any file by putting a new file with the same name in the child theme. That only works with templates loaded via `get_template_part`.

**A PHP file in a child theme, or a JS/CSS file in a child theme does not override the same file in the parent theme.**

So if you enqueue a CSS file in the parent theme, then copy the `functions.php` to the child theme and change it, it has not overriden the parent. Instead:

- both `functions.php` files run
- all the duplicated code now runs twice
- the original JS is enqueued, as well as the new JS file you tried to overwrite it with